# Input Date format Produce Error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted to string

Tags: php, datetime

I am trying to increment 1 month from my given date and I am receiving the following error while converting;

**Note:** Kindly check the comment in the code.

> Catchable fatal error: Object of class DateTime could not be converted
>   to string

My Code:

```
$start_date = '25-05-2015'; // 25th of May 2015
$dateVal = explode("-",$start_date);
$newdate = $dateVal[1].'-'.$dateVal[0].'-'.$dateVal[2].' 00:00:00'; // Converted

$cal_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $newdate);

$date = new DateTime($cal_date); // To give an standard format for this input only all the above date calculations are made. Pls specify any useful method?

$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

$date->add($interval);

$currentDate = $date->format('Y-m-d');
```

How can I convert the date to find the date after one month?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just reuse your `$cal_date`, no need to feed a new `$date` object into it:

```
$start_date = '25-05-2015'; // 25th of May 2015
$dateVal = explode("-",$start_date);
$newdate = $dateVal[1].'-'.$dateVal[0].'-'.$dateVal[2].' 00:00:00'; // Converted

$cal_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $newdate);

$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');

$cal_date->add($interval);
$currentDate = $cal_date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $currentDate;
```

The problem is, you're trying to feed a `DateTime` object instead of a string. It already says it in the error:

```
$cal_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('m-d-Y H:i:s', $newdate);
// ^ date time object
$date = new DateTime($cal_date); // feeding the DateTime Object into the constructor
```

Or why not just directly set the format in place, remove that part wherein you're exploding. You don't actually need those:

```
$start_date = '25-05-2015';
$cal_date = DateTime::createFromFormat('d-m-Y H:i:s', $start_date . ' 00:00:00');
$interval = new DateInterval('P1M');
$cal_date->add($interval);
$currentDate = $cal_date->format('Y-m-d');
echo $currentDate;
```